# Refactoring a Power Curve formula using C or C++

Tags: c, math, signals, formula, curve

I am trying to refactor this formula in C or C++. The use of POW is really expensive cpu wise even when I use something like a fasterpow approximation.

Is there a way to not use pow and still get a fitted curve to alter an input signal in both convex and concave directions. As long as I can get a similar curve it would be nice if there was a alternative that is faster but generally gives a convex or concave shape starting at 0 ending at 10.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

[image]

```
//input signal 0 to 10
//curve -10 to 10

negCurve = clamp(curve,-10,0);
posCurve = clamp(curve,0,10);

negativef(x)=fasterpow((x*0.1),((-negCurve+1)*10);
positivef(x)=fasterpow((x*0.1),(((1)/(1+posCurve))*10);
```

This is the approximation

```
static inline float 
fasterlog2 (float x)
{
  union { float f; uint32_t i; } vx = { x };
  float y = (float)(uint32_t)(vx.i);
  y *= 1.1920928955078125e-7f;
  return y - 126.94269504f;
}

static inline float
fastpow(float x,
    float p)
{
    return fastpow2(p * fastlog2(x));
}
```

Comment: What is the "fasterpow" approximation you are using?  Can you show how much "pow" and "fasterpow" is slowing down your program?  What machine are you programming for?

Comment: I posted the approximation I am using from a standard fastmath.h above edited to update what I am using. The performance is fine for a power calculation much better then C++ 17 powf etc I would like to find an alternate way not using pow but still be able to fit a convex/concave curve to a signal. I am programing for MAC and PC big sur and windows 10.

Comment: I did try this which actually does provide a curve like fitting but it seems to throw status errors in the debug monitoring utility. This means the code is other not going to sleep or shutting down or there is some kind of calculation issue that is going on. This formula works is cheaper then pow but I get some odd errors from it this is formula (((1 - (1 / posCurve2) * (x - 1)) + x) / x)

Comment: Ok for anybody reading this to get the (((1 - (1 / posCurve2) * (x - 1)) + x) / x) to work you have to make the final denominator X a volatile double or float. This was acting funky with the compiler at first throwing maybe denormals. However this is a suitable replacement curve fitting function that beats a fastpow based equivalent by around 50% cpu hit. Now I can set curves and it won't break the bank. This is faster then a LUT if only one curve is needed so nice savings with this. Anymore points a LUT will beat it cheers!

Comment: If you found the solution, post it as an answer, especially to keep this site from seeing this question as unanswered.

Comment: I found a different way to make a curve but I would still like to know the answer to the faster power function. I have explored AVX and SSE options seems like the best results so far. I have heard of other methods like unrolling loops that could be easy for the compiler to include these intrinsic boosts automatically regardless of architecture. So I have found something but I guess not the answer. Got any ideas there Pete-r?